# since 1980 vs from 1980

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

Why is "since 1980" instead of "from 1980" used? Can I use "from 1980"?

> The graph below gives information from a 2008 report about consumption of energy in the USA **since 1980** with projections until 2030.

[image]

Comment: "from" would require an end time, "since" implies that then end time is *now*. If there is *only * data from 1980 (which is not the case here; here the data is *from* 1980 *until* now with additional predictions until 2030), then you can say that the data is "from 1980"

Comment: In future please transcribe or OCR relevant text included in an image, and indicate the source of any quoted text or image, with a link as well as the name of the source  if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "from" could be used with an end-date as described in the [answer by Yash Laddha](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/318467/91457). Or "from" can be used with "onwards" or "until now" to specify the present as the end date. If "from" is used without any end date specified, the assumption is that the relevant period is quite brief. When the date is given as just a year, a bare "from" would indicate a period of less than a year.

For example:

> - (A) The graph below gives information from a 2008 report about consumption of energy in the USA from 1980.
> - (B) The graph below gives information from a 2008 report about consumption of energy in the USA from 1980 onwards.
> - (C) The graph below gives information from a 2008 report about consumption of energy in the USA since 1980.

Sentence (A) means that the information is all about consumption in 1980, not later. Sentences (B) and (C) both mean that the data covers the period 1980-2008. If the date of the report was not given,  (B) and (C) would both mean that the data covers the period from 1980 to the prsent.

Comment: I changed "period mod" to "period of", which I assume is what you meant.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan  correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

"from" requires a specified end time with "to". If, for example, the data ended at 1990, then you could've used "from 1980 to 1990".

However, "since" automatically assumes that the event is ongoing, i.e., hasn't ended (just like the dataset you've given).

To use "from" in this case, you would have add "onwards" to it: "... in the USA from 1980 onwards with..."

Comment: 'From' does not require a corresponding 'to'.  It is perfectly common to use it alone.  Also, 'onwards' is not required but is acceptable.

Comment: @Chenmunka If "from" is used alone the meaning is different as described in my answer.